# Key Algorithm Reverse

Tags: debugging, decryption

I am trying to reverse a Seed/Key algorithm. i have some sample and knowledge about it, for example i know this algorithm work with only "xor" and "shift" operations. 
some sample shown in below:

     `seed            key
  ---------       ----------
 0x01010101       0xDFBB4565
 0x02020202       0x21028781
 0x02010101       0xB1C7ED2B
 0x08010101       0xFB9718DE`

is this enough for reverse this algorithm?
according to the this [Question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23256/seed-key-constant-value/23257#23257) i know this algorithm will be must like each other but i dont know what is difference between them.
how i can reverse this algorithm and how i can reverse anything like this?

Comment: Usually `seed` is an additional input factor that changes the generated key. Hence you are missing the first input parameter (a password, a key or a static key dependent on what is used by the program the code comes from).

Comment: thanks Robert, yes of course but `seed` mean is different here. `seed` is input of a function that generate `key` as output.that function have a loop for 0x23 time(-or another value) and shifitng and xor,( i decribe this function in https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23256/seed-key-constant-value/23257#23257.  so i can't calculate this constant value AND i like to know generally, how i can reverse kind of this algorithms. thanks,